# Unknown Spacing at Top of Popup

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am trying to create a popup using the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit package but the popup is rendering with extra spacing across the top. Because of hardware limitations I am forced to develop using a much older version of CommunityToolkit (1.2.0) and Xamarin.Forms (5.0) so the issue may be from this.

This is the sample popup I am trying to render.

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
           Size="300,300"
           Color="Blue"
           x:Class="floorplanner.Dialogs.RoomDetailsDialog"
           xct:Clip="">
    <Label Text="Hello World" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
</xct:Popup>
```

This is what the popup looks like when it's opened:

[image]

So far I have tried configuring my MainTheme to have:

```xaml
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I have also tried specifying the size in a child layout element instead of the popup itself but it still rendered with the top spacing.

I have tried setting the VerticalOptions of the label to "Fill" and it still rendered as shown in the image. Originally, I had the label inside of a StackLayout but I removed this nesting to simplify the example for this post.

From more experiments I found that the Label itself is still rendering with a height of 300 units and the bottom the the Label's region is being clipped off the bottom. So essentially, there are ~50 units of height that are being pushed off the bottom.

As a workaround the the problem I have set the background of popup to transparent and set the inner content of the popup to the height - 50.

Comment: have you tried setting the VerticalOptions of the Label, or putting it inside a StackLayout?

Answer (score 0):

As you set the `Color="Blue"`, the whole background of [popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup#properties) is **blue**.

You add a label to in the popup layout however you haven't set the location of the label. You can set **VerticalOptions** and **HorizontalOptions** to set the location.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
       Size="300,300"
       Color="Blue"
       x:Class="floorplanner.Dialogs.RoomDetailsDialog"
       xct:Clip="">

    <Label Text="Hello World" BackgroundColor="Green" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

</xct:Popup>
```

Reference links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but the solution hasn't helped. Even with the Vertical Options set to start, I am not able to place the label any higher than it currently is. Even when the Vertical Options are set to fill, the green label doesn't draw over the top portion.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .